# volume size in aws console does not match size given by lsblk command after enlarging

Tags: amazon-web-services, volume

I'm trying to enlarge a standard nvme volume attached to an instance. After enlarging the instance to 5GB, the aws console website reports that it is 5 GB. However, when I run the lsblk command on the instance, it still shows it is at 4 GB.

I tried mounting and unmounting the volume's device but that didn't help.

Comment: Rebooting the instance fixed the issue. But I'm not sure why I had to reboot. I was under the impression there was no need to. This is a newly created volume.

Comment: This is confusing because 8GB should be the smallest size allowed for EBS and ephemeral drives are not size adjustable

Comment: What do you mean by ephemeral?

This isn't a root volume. It's just a regular volume attached to an instance.

Comment: When booting, there is code that runs `resize2fs` on the _root_ volume. Not sure if it runs on other volumes too.

Comment: Older kernels can't detect the new size - hence the need for a reboot